# How to illustrate angular data series in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, angle

I have a data set where the series values are angles in degrees (0 to 360). Is it possible to plot a graph like the one illustrated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrCTs.png) (ignore the green vertical line) in highcharts? Specifically, if any of the following criteria holds, the chart should avoid linking the two data points directly in the sense of passing through south (180), and should pass through north (0/360) instead:

1. A point is below 90 and the next one is above 270, or;
2. A point is above 270 and the next one is below 90.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do to make this happen is to simply pre-process your data to create two series and then plot both of them onto the same plot.  One series is for 0-179 and the other is for 180-359.

You may also want to consider a scatter plot instead of a line plot especially if your data in either of the series is not as smooth as the data in the example.  Meaning that one data point is say 10 and the next one is 110 and then the next one after that is 12 or some such.

This code gives you an example, the data is provided by JSON but you should be able to just easily replace it with however your data comes in:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        title: {
            text: 'Wind Direction'
        },
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'dataplot4',
            borderWidth: 1,
            defaultSeriesType: 'scatter',
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 3,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            tickInterval: 90,
            min: 0,
            max: 360,
            title: {
                text: 'Wind Direction (deg)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true,
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b %Y, %H:00', this.x) + ' AKST</b> ' +
                        this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + ' deg';
            }
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Wind Direction',
                data: JSON.parse("[" + wind_dir + "]"),
                pointStart: Number(startDateTime),
                pointInterval: 3600000
            }
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

I'd like to think that I have a jsfiddle for this somewhere, will update the answer when I dig it up.

EDIT: Here's a fiddle that shows the scatter plot in action. http://jsfiddle.net/Reality_Extractor/pNFYL/

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I really need the points to be connected. I think my data is dense enough (at 5-minute intervals, making a total of 288 points). A compromise, as you mentioned, is to break down the series, but it looks weird if there is no line between two values that are sufficiently far away from the border but should logically pass through north (0/360) rather than south (180) if one goes from the first to the second. An example would be for the first point to be around 70 and the second around 290. I've edited the question to make this more explicit.

Comment: Oh I just think of a possible way if I break the series into several parts, which is to add a point that goes off the y-axis range. This would require significant modification of the source data though. A simpler procedure to achieve this is obviously desired...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's what you need, but how about adding null values to split series into a few parts? Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/pNFYL/16/